# WPF open source projects

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, open-source

I am starting to learn now WPF programming, and I am looking for open projects with code that I can started with. Any project recommendations will be a good. I have searched here on the site but couldn't find any  WPF projects that I can start digging in.

I have seen [these links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553320/the-best-wpf-open-source-projects-youve-seen) already but they are not so good.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The best WPF open source projects you've seen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553320/the-best-wpf-open-source-projects-youve-seen)

Comment: i have found following good examples http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsamples

Comment: http://wpf.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many, many projects that use or develop extensions for WPF in [codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com). Check the WPF releases page [here](http://wpf.codeplex.com/), first.

Then take a look at [WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) and [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/).

Finally, [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) that shows MVVM in action may not be the best example for WPF (since it's trying to show you MVVM, after all), but it's a place to understand the strength of WPF (binds!).

Answer (score 1):

Pretty good start is famous [MSDN article about MVVM by Josh Smith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

There is also demo app code available.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [Magellan](http://code.google.com/p/magellan-framework/) to begin with WPF development. Magellan is a MVC based framework for WPF and

> Magellan's goal is to create a pit of success for WPF applications.

[The tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/magellan.aspx) is rather good so it should be an easy start and

Answer (score 0):

there are good WPF projects in Codeplex

check it out & find the best for you

http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=wpf&sortBy=Relevance&licenses=|&ac=8